# React Native Material Dropdown - How do you create auto fill/select dropdown base of JSON data structure?

Tags: react-native, autocomplete, dropdown

I have a structure json like this:

```
"diagnosis": [{
  "name": "kode",
  "value": [
    {"value": "kode1"},{"value": "kode2"},{"value": "kode3"}
  ]},
  {
  "name": "Primary Category",
  "value": [
    {"value": "PriCat1","id": "kode1"},
    {"value": "PriCat2","id": "kode2"},
    {"value": "PriCat3","id": "kode3"}
  ]},
  {
  "name": "Location",
  "value": [
    {"value": "Loc1","id": "kode1"},
    {"value": "Loc2","id": "kode2"},
    {"value": "Loc3","id": "kode3"}
  ]}
]
```

and for now, I can rendering those json with this code:

```
renderingMenu(){
  var tempListCheckBox = this.state.diagnosis.map(function(item,index){
  let data = item.value;
  return(
    <View>
      <Text style={[global.global.Text, {padding:DeviceWidth*0.02}]}>{item.name} :</Text>
      {/* https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown */}
      <Dropdown
        dropdownOffset={{top:5}}
        containerStyle={{borderWidth:1, borderColor:'lightgrey', borderRadius:50, width:DeviceWidth*0.8, paddingLeft:DeviceWidth*0.02}}
        rippleCentered={true}
        inputContainerStyle={{ borderBottomColor: 'transparent' }}
        data={data}
        valueExtractor={({value})=> value}
        onChangeText={(value)=>{this.onChangeTextPress(item.name, value)}}
      />
    </View>
  )
  }.bind(this))
  return tempListCheckBox;
}
```

here's the result of my code:

[image: Dropdown]

But I need to handle when the `kode:` label already selected with the value `kode1`, all the rest of dropdown will auto selected, like `Primary Category` value = `PriCat1`, and `Location` value = `Loc1`

Example:

[image: Example]

I've spent a couple hours to find any code, but still no luck,

anyone have an idea how to do that?

Edited:

```
onChangeTextPress(key, value){
  this.state.selected[key] = value;
  this.setState({selected: this.state.selected});
  console.log(this.state.selected);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to set first values as default or you have data for selected values?

Comment: @bennygenel actually I want to set a `placeholder` for all dropdown, but about your question, I don't want to set first values of `kode`, even a user selecting the 2nd dropdown first, it's ok

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: @bennygenel [here is a link of lib I'm used](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown)

Comment: set value prop for dropdown to make it selected with a state value. onChangeText update that state value.

Comment: @bennygenel i don't get it yet about your suggesting, at `onChangeText` i just save a `key` and `value` of selected dropdown

Comment: Can you please add the code from `onChangeText` to your question?

Comment: @bennygenel edited, please take a look of the code

Answer (score 2):

To set a value for the dropdown component you need to use `value` prop and in your `onChangeText` you need to set selected value again. You are already setting the value in your state but with a small mistake. You shouldn't be mutating state directly. You can use functional `setState`.

**Example**

```
onChangeTextPress(key, value){
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    let selected = Object.assign({}, prevState.selected);
    selected[key] = value;
    return { selected };
  }, () => {
    // because setState is async you need to use a callback
    // to be sure of the state set before using a state value
    console.log(this.state.selected);
  });
}

//...

renderingMenu(){
  var tempListCheckBox = this.state.diagnosis.map(function(item,index){
  let data = item.value;
  return(
    <View>
      <Text style={[global.global.Text, {padding:DeviceWidth*0.02}]}>{item.name} :</Text>
      {/* https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown */}
      <Dropdown
        dropdownOffset={{top:5}}
        containerStyle={{borderWidth:1, borderColor:'lightgrey', borderRadius:50, width:DeviceWidth*0.8, paddingLeft:DeviceWidth*0.02}}
        rippleCentered={true}
        inputContainerStyle={{ borderBottomColor: 'transparent' }}
        data={data}
        valueExtractor={({value})=> value}
        onChangeText={(value)=>{this.onChangeTextPress(item.name, value)}}

        // set value from state if its set
        // or use default as first value from the data
        value={this.state.selected[item.name] || data[0].value}

      />
    </View>
  )
  }.bind(this))
  return tempListCheckBox;
}
```

Comment: the code you used is displaying all the first index, but when i change the dropdown value from `kode1` to `kode2`, the entire dropdown won't change, and `this.state.selected` log just displaying `{ kode: 'kode2' }`, anyway I'm appreciate your help sir, +1